# winapi - How can I add multiple Menu bars to a Frame in MFC programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I know how to manipulate the top level CMenu for a CFrameWnd,(CFrameWnd::SetMenu) but I wondered how I can add multiple Menu bars to the Frame? Would this maybe require using Toolbars instead?

Comment: That would not impress the end user, rather it will confuse the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes a window can only have one true menu bar, if you want multiples then you would need to look at using toolbars instead.

Comment: Thought that was the case, cheers. Is there any tutorial you can suggest for creating a Menubar-like toolbar?

Comment: There is an ancient article on MSDN (IE5 era) on emulating the menubar style with rebars and toolbars and how they did it for IE5. I don;t have the link to hand though.

Comment: Is this it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775452(v=vs.85).aspx